# Stopping ajax polling in jsf primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am using prime-faces 3.2. Ajax polling is not get stopped, i am using stop attribute to stop the polling and i am trying to stop it form the bean using getter and setters for stop.
Even i have used java script to stop but i can't. Any solution to stop polling?

Comment: Wow... you really should start marking answers as "Correct" for your previous answers.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pollStartStop.jsf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this code works like a charm in my case:

```
 <p:poll  interval="2" update="flightsTable" widgetVar="poll"  
         autoStart="false" listener="#{searchFlightBean.checkIfSearchCompleate}"/>
```

Method in searchFlightBean:

```
public void checkIfSearchCompleate() {
    if(searchCompleate) {
        RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        reqCtx.execute("poll.stop();");
    }
}
```

Comment: poll call will get stopped. but in firebug i can able to see the call running.it get stopped only after page refresh

Comment: did you ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<p:poll id="checkListPoll" interval="2" process="@none" 
        update="checkList" widgetVar="chkList"/>
<h:panelGroup id="checkList"> ... </h:panelGroup>
```

You can use this from controller to stop ajax requests:

```
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('chkList').stop()"); //after Primefaces 7.0
```

or with older Primefaces version:

```
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
...
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('chkList').stop()"); //before Primefaces 7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
<h:panelGroup id="chartPanel">
    <h:graphicImage value="#{resource['img:loading.gif']}" 
        rendered="#{!indexController.chartReady}"> 
        <p:poll  interval="1" update="chartPanel" autoStart="true" />
    </h:graphicImage> 
    <p:chart id="chart" type="line" model="#{indexController.chartModel}" 
        rendered="#{indexController.chartReady}" /> 
</h:panelGroup>
```

The polling is stopped when chartReady is true, no futher code in the bean